# Changed pom but didn't affect to module

Tags: maven, dependencies, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I use IntelliJ IDEA and running a Maven application. My application uses some other modules, projects. I changed version of one module's dependencies(I changed a hibernate dependency' artifact id from hibernate to hibernate-core and changed version too).

However when I see my dependency tree I still see the old library. What should I do. Should I clean, install or do something like that for that module(I tried install but couldn't passed tests, is skipping tests is a good idea and how can I do that?).

Any ideas?

Comment: These are several questions, please split.

Comment: Just one question actually, others are optional.

Comment: @kamaci Did you try reimport project?

Comment: @kamaci You can also try to delete artifact (or some of artifacts) from your local repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rebuild and install your module (the one with Hibernate dependency) at least to the local repository (mvn clean install), then update dependencies in other modules which use your module. In Eclipse it's called Update Depcendecies, I suppose IntelliJ IDEA has a similar feature.

If your module does not compile or test fails, fix them first or install it only to the local repository. Later you can delete them from your local repo.